# while loop with 2 conditions

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have been struggling with a small loop. I do not know why my `while` loop does not work. If I remove one of the 2 conditions it works, but when both are together it does not...

```
temp = input("Choose between Fahreneit degrees 'f'' key or Celsius degrees 'c' key ")

while temp != "f" or temp != "c" :
 temp = input("you must choose f or c")

if (temp == "f") :
 print("you choosed Fahreneit")
 degF = int(input("What is the temperature outside?"))
 print("It seems that the temperature is around" , (0.56 * (degF - 32)) ,"Celsius from your Fahreneit sample")

elif (temp == "c") :
 print("you choosed Celsius")
 degC = int(input("What is the temperature outside?"))
 while degC < -273 or degC > 5500 :
  degC = int(input("Please enter a correct value"))

print("it seems that the temperature is around" , (1.8 * (degC) + 32) , "Fahreneit from your Celsius sample")
```

Comment: "I have been struggling for a small poop." - classic.

Comment: One space is not enough - for readability follow the [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and indent by four spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp != "f" or temp != "c"` is not the opposite of `temp == "f" or temp == "c"`. See [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for guidance regarding the negation of boolean expressions.

Try:

```
while temp != "f" and temp != "c":
```

Or just:

```
while not (temp == "f" or temp == "c"):
```

Or skip the boolean headache entirely:

```
while temp not in ("f", "c"):
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin, i have to say i did not know about De Morgan's laws. The answer was the first try of you list.